# iPhone: how to download media files and save them on device

Tags: iphone

I am new in the iOs world and I need help to implement small feature in my application.

My question is how to download media files (i.e. mp4) and save them on the device for later use? off course the place that the files will be saved should be accessible from my app only (something similar to Context.getCacheDir() in Android).

thanks
-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your cache dir. For instance, you can find it by calling this code:

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the download and save part

Comment: Look at the NSURLConnection for asynchronous connections, implement the delegate methods, there's lots of sample code scattered everywhere, including apple's website on this. You'll also want to check out the reachability sample code as well.